# ImportError /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 - in several software packages

Tags: fedora, qt, ld

Working with Fedora 35: I want to run a few different software packages that share a dependency, seemingly Qt.

In the shell, I get this response, from Cadence and other software:

```
      ImportError: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5-5.15.6-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so)
```

`ldconfig -p | grep "libQt5Core.so.5"` gets me

```
    libQt5Core.so.5 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.17.0) => /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
```

If I remove `/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5` I get

```
     ImportError: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Reinstalling `python3-pyqt5-sip` or other  `qt`, `lib` or `python` dependencies does not seem to help.

So, `libQt5Core.so.5` is found by the system, but it does not work. Though others with Fedora 35 do not have this problem. How can I provide Pathon with the required `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API`?

Comment: why do you have a PyQt5 installation at /usr/local/lib/python...? The one that fedora brings will be under /usr/lib/python...; so, most likely you're reinstalling a PyQt that gets ignored in favor of this non-functional /usr/local installation.

Comment: Thank you @MarcusMüller. This got me on the right track! Another non-Fedora package had installed these there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @MarkusMüller, I traced back the issue to another package that had installed PyQt at an unexpected place.

The solution was to remove the other package and its dependencies. Then reinstalling Cadence worked and it ran.

Comment: What package was causing the problem?

Comment: thanks @ingframin, sorry, but I cannot recall...

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when use julialang in jupyter notebook at my Fedora 36, because I use anaconda, the problem solved by replace libQt5Core.so.5 at directory anaconda3/lib with file libQt5Core.so.5 /usr/lib64

Answer (score -1):

try to install qt5-default (that's the debian package name)

Comment: thanks, but I work with Fedora, as the question has specified.